# Prove that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{{(\prod_{a=1}^{n} {a^{a^{p}}}})^\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}}{n^{\frac{1}{p+1}}} = e^{-\frac{1}{(p+1)^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{{(\prod_{a=1}^{n} {a^{a^{p}}}})^\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}}{n^{\frac{1}{p+1}}} = e^{-\frac{1}{(p+1)^2}}$$

I tried taking ln of the limit and applying stolz cesaro but I didn't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the ln you can rewrite it as :

$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{a=1}^{n}(\frac{a}{n})^{p}\ln(\frac{a}{n}) + (\sum_{a=1}^{n}(\frac{a}{n})^{p}-\frac{1}{p+1})\ln(n) $

Now if you use Riemann integral property you find that the sum on the left converges to $\frac{-1}{(p+1)^2}$ and the right term converges to zero hence the result.

Comment: a slight typo, the second term must be $(\sum_{a=1}^{n}(\frac{a}{n})^{p}-\frac{n}{p+1}) \frac{\ln(n)}{n} = (\frac{ \sum_{a=1}^{n}{a^p}}{{n}^{p+1}}-\frac{1}{p+1}) \ln(n)$.

Comment: But other than that, very nice solution